# D3 v4 Brush and Zoom on the same element (without mouse events conflicting)

Tags: d3.js

My goal is to build a D3 (v4) chart that uses both [d3-zoom](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom) and [d3-brush](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush) together, as follows:

1. When the mouse is positioned over the x-axis, the user can zoom (with the mouse wheel) or pan (by dragging left and right)
2. When the mouse is positioned over the y-axis, the user can zoom (with the mouse wheel) or pan (by dragging up and down)
3. When the mouse is positioned over the chart body, the user can zoom (with the mouse wheel) or brush to set the x domain to a specific range

I have managed to implement both zooming and panning on the appropriate axes (as per requirements 1 & 2), but am having problems combining the two together to achieve requirement 3.

I have done the following, based on the docs/examples:

- For brushing, append a `g` SVG element and call the `brush` on that element. The library creates a `rect` with class `overlay` inside that, and attaches the appropriate mouse events to let me draw a brush region inside that space.
- For zooming, append a `rect` SVG element and call the `zoom` on that element. The library hooks up the appropriate mouse events to allow me to scroll up and down with the mouse wheel inside that space.

**The problem I have is in the combination of these two approaches. Because both `zoom` and `brush` create a `rect` and handle mouse events, only one works at a time. The SVG element that is created last "steals" the mouse input and does not propagate it to the other. How can I get the two to play nicely together on the main chart area?**

I have an example project which shows the problem. It's based on Angular & TypeScript but can be run as follows:

1. Checkout my example at https://github.com/mattwilson1024/d3-zoom-and-brush
2. Run the app by running `npm install` or `yarn install`, then `npm start` or `yarn start`
3. Open `http://localhost:4200`
4. You can zoom&pan on the two axes, or brush the main chart area. The zoomable regions are coloured green and red to help debug
5. Open /src/app/char/chart.component.ts and uncomment line 196. This moves the x-axis "zoom region" (rect) to cover the whole body of the chart. That means that you can use the wheel to zoom-x with the mouse anywhere over the chart.
6. The problem is that now the zoom region "steals" the mouse event from the brush, so brushing is no longer possible, and it pans instead. Instead of the panning behaviour that `d3-zoom` sets up, I want to be able to brush by dragging the mouse, but still zoom with the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue today. As you pointed out, the zoom and brush behaviors steal eachother's events, so you'll have to establish them on different elements.

This article has an excellent overview of how to do it:
http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/09/19/d3-svg-chart-performance.html

Essentially it amounts to creating an SVG rect to specifically handle the zoom events. You can leave your brush behavior attached to an svg group.

Also see the demo here:
http://tlsim.github.io/sl-blog-d3/ohlcSemanticZoom.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Attaching the zoom behaviour to an SVG rect allows the scrolling to work on the chart body, but it also has the effect of "stealing" the input from the brush. What I'm after is for the mouse wheel to zoom, but to be able to drag a brush as well (instead of the default panning behaviour that the zoom plugin adds). In other words, I only want the zoom plugin to add zooming, not panning.

Comment: Ahhh. Okay. So, zooming and panning should work in conjunction, but I haven't found any other way to make zooming, panning, and rectangle-selection brushing work together. What we've done in our project is actually have a zoom-mode toggle. Default is panning and scroll-zoom, but you can toggle into rectangle-select mode. If you go this route, you can do something as simple as introducing a css class, representing the toggle, which will disable pointer events for one of the modes.

Comment: Same problem here. Any other solutions found?

Comment: ran into the same problem any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact d3.zoom ([source](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/src/zoom.js)), adds an event listener `mousedowned` for `mousedown` events. `mousedowned` calls `event.stopImmediatePropagation`, and thereby, prevents other `mousedown` listeners (in your case, that of `brush`) from listening. Since you don't want panning over the chart body, you can remove this listener.

```
chartbody.on("mousedown.zoom", null)
```

This will stop `zoom` from listening to `mousedown` and stopping the event propagation.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get a working solution to this challenge as I was facing it too. Zoom incorporates event.stopPropagation(). This means that any events triggered on elements contained within a parent element will not "bubble up" to the parent element. 
See MDN to understand bubbling and how it works, with a nice example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture

This is how I understand it working and what I have rationalised to get my solution working:
For brushing, the event will propagate up to ancestor elements. In your case up to the svg-element. In your case you have appended a rect-element to the svg and attached your zoom behaviour to the rect. Therefore, the element with the zoom is not a parent of the element with the brush, but rather an "uncle/aunt", as if you traversed directly back up the DOM tree you would get back to the svg and never the rect.

If you instead attach the zoom behaviour to the svg so that it is an ancestor of the group element with the brush action, this will allow the action on the g element to bubble up to the svg. Now your zoom can also fire as the event will bubble up. In this case just incorporate a check to see what the source of the event was, i.e. was it the brush or zoom action. Based on the result of the check you can then apply the zoom, if and only if, the zoom action is what triggered the zoom event to fire, otherwise apply the brushing method.